# Problem with live countdown clock

Tags: php, javascript, date, time

Basically I currently have the clock presenting the time however the countdown isn't working. I have taken the code originally from [here](http://scripts.franciscocharrua.com/countdown-clock.php) and have adapted it.

What I am trying to do is get the countdown to count down from a duration time I have retrieved from my database.

here is how I retrieve my duration time:

```
//TRANSFORM MYSQL TIME INTO SECONDS

    $duration_array = explode(':', $duration);

    $length = ((int)$duration_array[0] * 3600) + ((int)$duration_array[1] * 60) + (int)$duration_array[2];

    //CALCULATE FINISH TIME WITH START TIME AND DURATION.
    $target_time = $length + time();
```

I am parsing this to my JavaScript countdown function successfully and converting into a javascript date() object.

However currently the clock doesn't count down.

Here is my javascript:

```
function countdown_clock(target_time)
         {
         html_code = '<div id="countdown"></div>';

         document.write(html_code);

     var timetarget = new Date(target_time *1000);

         countdown(timetarget);

         }


function countdown(timetarget)
         {

     var Today = new Date();

     Todays_Year = Today.getFullYear() - 2000;
         Todays_Month = Today.getMonth();

         //Convert both today's date and the target date into miliseconds.
         Todays_Date = (new Date(Todays_Year, Todays_Month, Today.getDate(),Today.getHours(),Today.getMinutes(),Today.getSeconds())).getTime();

     Target_Date = timetarget.getTime();

         //Find their difference, and convert that into seconds.
         Time_Left = Math.round((Target_Date - Todays_Date) / 1000);

         if(Time_Left < 0)
            Time_Left = 0;

        var innerHTML = '';

         //More datailed.
        days = Math.floor(Time_Left / (60 * 60 * 24));
        Time_Left %= (60 * 60 * 24);
        hours = Math.floor(Time_Left / (60 * 60));
        Time_Left %= (60 * 60);
        minutes = Math.floor(Time_Left / 60);
        Time_Left %= 60;
        seconds = Time_Left;

    if (seconds < 10){seconds = '0' + seconds;}
    if (minutes < 10){minutes = '0' + minutes;}

        innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' secs' ;

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = innerHTML;

         //Recursive call, keeps the clock ticking.
        setTimeout('countdown('+timetarget+');', 1000);
        }
```

I really seem to be struggling with the whole date stuff so any help would be great.

thanks,

Comment: Where are you looping your countdown and what is the exact reaction you're seeing from your javascript?  You mention it's not counting down, but you don't have anything looping your countdown function in what you've listed here

Comment: well what I am trying is, I call the countdown function every 1000 miliseconds with my setTimeout(). And everytime countdown is called it gets the current time and finds the difference based on that, so theoretically the time will have changed by one second the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was that your `timetarget` variable was losing the fact that it was a `Date` object. I fixed it and [made a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/N3rcw/), and it seems to be working (counting down).

**EDIT**: additionally, I think Javascript might have been screwing up because you were using `innerHTML` as a variable name, and that's another change I made.

**EDIT 2**: here's an update with some [slightly cleaned up code](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/N3rcw/3/).

Comment: `Todays_Date = (new Date()).getTime();` this bit here, I thought I had to pass that information so it only contained those values I specified, not all the other stuff.